# Pegar link mp3 do arquivo no Soundcloud

Tags: html

Possuo uma ferramenta, onde devo informar o link exato do arquivo mp3 que consta no Soundcloud. No caso, não seria o link do áudio em si e sim onde o arquivo está hospedado.
Atualmente estou utilizando o site http://offliberty.me/ para esse tipo de processo.

Se eu pegar o embed de um arquivo, estará assim:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/328259811&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

Tentei usar o que está após o **api.soundcloud...** e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Do modo que você quer fazer é possível.

Você precisa obter a seguinte URL que está localizado no `iframe`

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/328259811
```

Você pode verificar direto no browser as propriedades, se a propriedade `downloadable` estiver marcado como `true`, automaticamente a propriedade `download_url` estará definida com o link para download.

Comment: Como eu faço para verificar essas propriedades? Preciso do link direto para o arquivo.

Comment: Depende de como você está obtendo o iframe, você não deixou claro se é de forma dinâmica ou manual.

Comment: Pode ser manual.